# When do views get created?

Tags: objective-c, ios, uiwebview

I apologize in advance for the n00b question.  I am just getting started w/ iOS!

I am trying to push a webViewController onto a navigation controller.

```
mudWebViewController *webViewController = [[mudWebViewController alloc] initWithNibName:nil bundle:nil];
[[webViewController webView] setDelegate:webViewController];
[[self navigationController] pushViewController:webViewController animated:YES];
```

But this doesn't seem to work, as I don't see any of the logs in the delegate messages.

If I set the delegate in the viewDidLoad: method, it works fine.

I guess the webView doesn't actually exist at that point, but why?  If I initialize the controller, shouldn't the webView be initialized too?

Is viewDidLoad: the right place to be setting up this stuff?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

initWithNibName should be not nil, since you obviously are using a nib file to build the view, else you have to create the view in code, which you don't

```
mudWebViewController *webViewController = [[mudWebViewController alloc] initWithNibName:@"webViewController" bundle:nil];
[[self navigationController] pushViewController:webViewController animated:YES];
```

Also any delegates should be set either from the Interface builder or from the view itself in the viewDidLoad delegate and not from the previous class, as the object might not been yet initialized in the code so it can fail to set the delegate properly.

Comment: Thanks.  Totally forgot you could connect the delegate in the interface builder.  Also, if do leave initWithNibName:nil it will look for a nib with the same name as the controller.  Obviously safer to be explicit, but still works that way too.